# Spring Boot HTTP Client of multiple servers WITHOUT load balancer

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I'm running Spring Boot services in AWS ECS using CloudMap.
Using Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE

`S(1)` and `S(2)` are exact copies of a CPU intensive service, and `C` is calling them as part of servicing multiple parallel requests.
`C` is not resource bound, so I don't want to create more instances of it.
Calls are HTTP/REST made using `com.konghq:unirest-java:jar:3.6.00`, which in turn uses `httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.11`

Here a little diagram:

```
Multiple Parallel Requests ---->  C (10.1.12.25) ---------> S(1) (10.1.178.143)
                                                     \
                                                      \---> S(2) (10.1.118.82)
```

Using Cloudmap as Service Directory, when I  `dig  <service-name>`, it returns both IPs in the answer.

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
<service-name>. 60  IN  A   10.1.178.143
<service-name>. 60  IN  A   10.1.118.82
```

Because C is only one instance, S(1) is receiving 100% of requests from C. This makes me think C is somehow using only one of the IP addresses registered as .

Is it posible to make `C` use BOTH IP addresses to invoke `<service-name>` without using a Load Balancer? Maybe configuring something in Unirest and/or HttpClient?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: This is my first question, so please be kind if not the right tag, etc. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Route53 with those ip address and chose a round robin policy.
How ever if the requests are ran in parallel  and you wan't to not over load any specific instance a load balancer is needed for the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, Route53 is being used internally by CloudMap to register the instances of `S` and multiple IP are returned by the DNS request (in this example using `dig`. But apparently `C` is asking for the IPs to DNS  only once in a while  and uses only one IP of `S` in consecutive request. I am looking for maybe a 'trick' to invoke ramdonly any of the IPs without me having to cache manually those IPs.